# How to do If () for range of values and by match criteria in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-analysis

I have two table from excel, one of the table is percentage of race A and B in year 2017 and another table percentage of race A and B in year 2018. If the races percentage in 2018 is greater than 2017 respectively and by country, It will print the race group in the comparison column. I have use IF statement to accomplish the comparison but have no idea on how to match the two table country and then proceed with if statement.

```
IF(J35,"M",IF(K35>K5,"A",IF(L35>L5,"B","X")))
```

Table 1 : 2017

| country | race A % | race B% |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K | 50 | 50 |
| L | 20 | 80 |
| M | 10 | 90 |

Table 2 : 2018

| country | race A % | race B% |
| --- | --- | --- |
| K | 40 | 60 |
| L | 10 | 90 |
| M | 95 | 5 |

Table 3 : Output

| country | race A % | race B% | Comparison |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| K | 40 | 60 | B |
| L | 10 | 90 | B |
| M | 95 | 5 | A |

Comment: Could you share the addresses of the first cell (`country`) of each table? Will the first column have the same values in each table, or will they be in a different order? I am assuming that the columns will be in the same order.

Comment: Table 3 has the same data as Table 2 2018. How exactly is Table 1 2017 involved?

Comment: @VBasic2008 the first column will be the same values/orders

Comment: Table 3 is resulted by comparing Table 1 and Table 2 , then append the result column "Comparison" to table 2.